# how to print when you have left a recursive call

Tags: java, recursion, printing

How can I print to the screen after leaving a recursive call. For example when doing the ackermann function bellow.

```
acker(1,2);
public int acker(int m, int n){
    System.out.println("Entered acker");
    if(m == 0)
        return n + 1;
    if(n == 0)
        return acker(m-1,1);
    return acker(m-1, acker(m, n - 1));
}
```

I can print when I enter the acker method but how would I print after the method finishes calling itself. For example the output would be:

```
Entered acker
Entered acker 
Entered acker 
Entered acker
//Here it would say leaving because its not making another recursive call
```

Comment: only if you monitored the recursion depth. instead why not just have a print statement after calling the functiong "left acker"

Comment: Just...print after the call returns...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor to assign the return value to a variable, print your message, then return the value:

```
public int acker(int m, int n){
    System.out.println("Entered acker");
    int result;
    if(m == 0)
        result = n + 1;
    else if(n == 0)
        result = acker(m-1,1);
    else
        result = acker(m-1, acker(m, n - 1));
    System.out.println( "Returning " + result + " from acker");
    return result; 
}
```